# Youtube Api V3 insert video without end-user auth

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I would like user upload video to youtube via my web site. I want to user upload on my youtube channel. But oAuth require user google/youtube login.

Is there a solution without OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload to Youtube video without login (via the browser or via oAuth).

Comment: Well have a single login? Does only main account (master account) login? I don't want users to login screen.

Comment: @maverabil Google may not allow to use your one account(and only the user account)

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer use the YouTube API to upload to YouTube without using OAuth.  "ClientLogin" is no longer supported.